# How to get 2-players locations and teleport them each to other location

Tags: java, eclipse, minecraft

*I need to get 2-players positions(on server only 2 players and i don`t know their names)
and then teleport first player to second(location) and second player to first(location)
like*

```java
Player firstplayer = Bukkit.getServer().getplayer(1);
Player secondplayer = Bukkit.getServer().getplayer(2);
    
Location firstloc = firstplayer.getLocation();
Location secondloc = secondplayer.getLocation();
    
firstplayer.teleport(secondloc);
secondplayer.teleport(firtsloc);
```

*how to do it?*

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled `firstloc`.

If that doesn't work, try creating a temporary Location variable like so:

```
Player firstplayer = Bukkit.getServer().getplayer(1);
Player secondplayer = Bukkit.getServer().getplayer(2);
    
Location firstloc = firstplayer.getLocation();
Location temp = firstloc;
Location secondloc = secondplayer.getLocation();
    
firstplayer.teleport(secondloc);
secondplayer.teleport(temp);
```